# Compare (and) insert (in) from a position std::array

Tags: c++, std, stdarray

I have a `std::array` with several items and I want to compare it from a certain position and also insert in a certain position, for example.

```
std::array<int, 10> numbers {{ 9, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 10, 15, 25 }};
```

I want to compare the *array numbers* from item 5 until the last one, with this one, from the beginning, that is position 0 until position 4.

```
std::array<int, 10> compare {{ 6, 1, 10, 15, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};
```

It will (in  this case) return true.

And how to insert items from a position? I want to insert on the *array compare* from the position 5 until the last position, that is 9.

For example, if I want to insert these numbers: 5, 45, 32, 14, 10. It will turn:

```
std::array<int, 10> compare {{ 6, 1, 10, 15, 25, 5, 45, 32, 14, 10 }};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second problem, use `std::copy`. `std::copy(insert.begin(), insert.end(), compare.begin() + 5);`

Comment: hint: such operations on containers are usually offered as ["algorithms"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: @remyabel - I saw somewhere that I could use that way, but I wonder, is it the only way?

Comment: look at `std::equal_range`, `std::copy`.

Comment: For the first problem, you can use `std::search`. `auto it = std::search(numbers.begin() + 5, numbers.end(), compare.begin(), compare.begin() + 5); if (it != numbers.end()) // found`

Comment: For comparing, I would std::equal, see  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5405218/104774